# Rust autocomplete - hide paths where stuff is found

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, rust, racer

When the autocomplete from company-racer kicks in, it shows the path where it is found for some reason. For example, if I start typing:

```
use std::i
```

it comes up with io /usr/src/rust/src/libstd/io/mod.rs : Module

How can I hide this path so it just suggests io?